# GULP watch not working in my gulp.js file

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

Hi im trying to get a gulp watch on the go in my gulp.js file. It needs to run my sass and minify it and set to destination folder on watch. Can anybody help please?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
    var sass = require('gulp-sass');
    var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    var watch = require('gulp-watch');
    var htmlmin = require('gulp-html-minifier');

    gulp.task('sass', function(){
      return gulp.src('scss/styles.scss')
        .pipe(sass()) // Converts Sass to CSS with gulp-sass
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
    });


    gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
      return gulp.src('dest/*.css')
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
    });

    gulp.task('compress', function() {
      return gulp.src('lib/*.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });

    gulp.task('minify-html', function() {
      gulp.src('*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(''))
    });

    // Watch Files For Changes
    gulp.task('watch', function(){
      gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']); 
      // Other watchers
    })

    // Run all Refinedby Tasks
    gulp.task('all', ['sass']);
```

Comment: Try to use `watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);` instead of `gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);`

Comment: no sorry that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any errors, or is it just not triggering when you save the SCSS file?

Comment: No errors, its just not triggering the SCSS when i save in sublime. Should update in git bash and let you know that sass has been compiled but it doesnt.

Comment: Try to change scss/*.css to scss/**/*.scss

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the watcher when you call your "all task command".

```
gulp.task('all', ['sass'], function() { 
       gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

or

```
gulp.task('all', ['sass'], function() { 
       gulp.start('watch');
});
```

or if you do not want to change your code just add

```
// Run all Refinedby Tasks
gulp.task('all', ['sass', 'watch']);
```